# OneSignal error on postNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, onesignal

I came back to some code I had been working on last year and updated everything, now my code isn't working. When I call post notification now I get "ERROR: Create notification failed"

what I have is this in my AppDelegate:

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "xxxxxx")
```

And here is my call to post:

```
let data = ["contents": ["en": "Push"], "include_player_ids": tokens] as [String : Any]

OneSignal.postNotification(data)
```

When I make the above call, I've checked that tokens is equal to:

["xxxxxxx"] where xxxxxx is a device token. Is there something I'm missing? I've checked that my version number for OneSignal is 2.3.4 and I've enabled the proper capabilities in my project settings. If no one knows what the problem is just from looking, is there a way to at least get more info from the error? Thank you

Comment: I never use OneSignal before but if it's related to push notification, then the development certificate only last 3 months where as production certificate last 1 year if I remember correctly... (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) maybe renewing your certificates will fix the problem.

Comment: Turned out I was trying to use the token when I needed to be saving 'userId' , but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Alex Yes indeed you should use 'userId' here instead of 'push token'. As for detailed error message, try this:  OneSignal.postNotification( ["contents": ["en": "Test Message"]], onSuccess: {(result) in print("success") }, onFailure: {(error) in print("error : \(error)") } )

Comment: @Alex Maybe you should conclude your comment and my comment to answer this question. And mark your own question as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I was trying to use the token when I needed to be saving 'userId' , but thanks for the suggestion!